# Is there any way to open more than one folders(Home folder, videps etc..) by clicking the 'files' icon on the unity bar?

Tags: unity, nautilus, window-manager

Why only one nautilus window manager is opens when clicking on the 'Files' icon on the unity bar? I need to open two or more HomeFolder windows by clicking on the 'files' icon on the unity pane. I cannot create more than one nautilus window manager unless i tap superkey(windows key) and type homefolder,videos etc or typing the same in gnome-do. Is there any way to open more than one folders(Home folder, videos etc..) by clicking the 'files' icon on the unity bar??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could change the entry list of right-click menu by using "Unity Launcher Editor". In this software there are options to add a new list entry. Anyway thanks to all for responding my question. I use 11.10.

Answer (score 5):

Use the middle mouse button to open a second instance of an application.

Or hold the <kbd>shift</kbd>-key while clicking with the left mouse button.

Comment: I usually use touch pad. So, I tried shift combination. It is not working.

Comment: You can simulate a middle mouse click by pressing the 2 buttons at the same time. This works either with a regular mouse or a touchpad.

Answer (score 3):

Try to right-click the **Home folder** icon at the Launcher, and in the *quicklist* that appears, click **Open a new Window**.

It's the first icon after the launcher one.

*It's on spanish, but in english it should be "Downloads, Documents, Images, Music, Videos, **Open a new window**, Personal Folder...).

I hope it works to you!

Comment: Options when i right-click are: 1) Files 2)Keep In Launcher

Comment: Updated with image, maybe I'm not understanding you

Comment: @user86865 on Ubuntu 12.04 LTS the option should be named "Lock to Launcher" and not "Keep in launcher". What version are you using?

Answer (score -1):

Use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd> in the first Nautilus (aka Files) window.

Comment: Title of the question: *"Is there any way to open more than one folders [...] **by clicking the 'files' icon on the unity bar**?"*